# Python 3: How to get a random 4 digit long number with no repeated digits inside that number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, numbers

Ok so I need my program to be able to get a random number that has no repeated digits inside that number. So like 0012 has two 0s and therefore I don't need that, however, 1234 would work. The numbers also need to be JUST 4 digits long.

```
import random
```

Comment: 0123 is not a number....

Comment: @Nullman Yes, `random.sample(range(10), 4)` will do the trick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use sample:

```
import random
numbers = random.sample(range(10), 4)
print(''.join(map(str, numbers)))
```

@Copperfield variation in the comments is elegant as it forgoes the need to cast (since you are sampling from a string).

```
import random
number = ''.join(random.sample("0123456789", 4))
print(number)
```

Comment: one variation: `''.join(random.sample("0123456789", 4))`

Answer (score 4):

```
from random import shuffle
l = [i for i in range(10)]
shuffle(l)
n = l[0] + 10 * (l[1] + 10 * (l[2] + 10 * l[3]))
```

Here's a oneliner

```
import random
from functools import reduce # you need this for python3
n = reduce(lambda a,b: 10*a+b, random.sample(range(10), 4))
```

**Note**: Both of the methods above might occasionally give a 3 digit number due to 0 appearing at the front

Comment: another variation: `sum( n*10**e for e,n in enumerate( random.sample(range(10),4)))`

Comment: @Copperfield: The code has been updated. `shuffle` works in-place, and `reduce` isn't python3.

Comment: @LakshayGarg: The comment was a bit too harsh, sorry. Thanks for the update. PS: I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 2):

There are only 5040 choices. If you need to generate these numbers many times, you may like to precompute a list of choices.

```
>>> import random, itertools
>>> choices = [''.join(x) for x in itertools.permutations('0123456789', 4)]
>>> random.choice(choices)
'0179'
>>> random.choice(choices)
'7094'
```

Comment: That's a clever answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.sample` in order to ensure no digits are repeated,

```
>>> import random
>>> l = random.sample(range(10), 4)
>>> int((''.join([str(x) for x in l])))
>>> 4265
```

Comment: How is this different from Aaron Taggart's answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the number into a string:

```
list_number = list(range(1, 10))
w = random.choice(list_number)
list_number.remove(w)
list_number.append(0)
x = random.choice(list_number)
list_number.remove(x)
y = random.choice(list_number)
list_number.remove(y)
z = random.choice(list_number)
x = int(str(w)+str(x)+str(y)+str(z))
print("x")
```